# Swift Implicitly pass self as inout parameter for reference type

Tags: swift

Is it possible to implicitly pass `self` as an `inout` parameter to modify a reference variable in place?

Here is a method which can convert an abstract base class into one of its concrete subclasses. My question is, must I always have that first argument, `obj: inout AbstractBaseClass`, or can I implicitly pass self. I realize that this might also be expressed as a static method.

```
    func convertTo(_ obj: inout AbstractBaseClass, _ type: ConcreteClassTypes) {
        switch type {
        case .concreteClass1: obj = ConreteClass1()
        case .concreteClass2: obj = ConcreteClass2()
        }
    }
```

Here is the full code:

```
class AbstractClass {

    enum ConcreteType {
        case concreteClass1
        case concreteClass2
    }

    var id: Int = 0

    fileprivate init() { }

    func convert(_ obj: inout AbstractClass, to type: ConcreteType) {

        let oldId = obj.id

        switch type {
        case .concreteClass1: obj = ConcreteClass1()
        case .concreteClass2: obj = ConcreteClass2()
        }

        obj.id = oldId
    }

    class ConcreteClass1: AbstractClass {

        override init() { super.init() }
    }

    class ConcreteClass2: AbstractClass {

        override init() { super.init() }

    }

}

var obj: AbstractClass = AbstractClass.ConcreteClass1()
obj.convert(&obj, to: .concreteClass2) //is there any way to eliminate this first argument?
```

Comment: "*which can convert an abstract base class into one of its concrete subclasses*" – why do you have an instance of the abstract base class to begin with? You don't generally want to instantiate an abstract class in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like matt, I'm not convinced that `inout` is the right tool for the job in this case.

Although that being said, if you insist on it, one way to achieve what you want is to (ab)use protocol extensions. They allow the definition of `mutating` methods, which pass the implicit `self` parameter as `inout` (to allow the mutation of adopting value types).

So you *could* say:

```
protocol AbstractClassProtocol {}

class AbstractClass : AbstractClassProtocol {

    enum ConcreteType {
        case concreteClass1
        case concreteClass2
    }

    fileprivate init() {}

    class ConcreteClass1: AbstractClass {
        override init() { super.init() }
    }

    class ConcreteClass2: AbstractClass {
        override init() { super.init() }
    }
}

extension AbstractClassProtocol where Self == AbstractClass {

    mutating func convert(to type: AbstractClass.ConcreteType) {
        switch type {
        case .concreteClass1:
            self = AbstractClass.ConcreteClass1()
        case .concreteClass2:
            self = AbstractClass.ConcreteClass2()
        }
    }
}

var obj: AbstractClass = AbstractClass.ConcreteClass1()
obj.convert(to: .concreteClass2)
print(obj) // AbstractClass.ConcreteClass2
```

But it's a bit of a hack, and I'd be wary about using it.

Answer (score 1):

> ...to modify a reference variable in place? Here is a method which can convert an abstract base class into one of its concrete subclasses...

You are not "modifying" or "converting" anything. You are *substituting* one object for another. Thus, there is no `self` that could be passed here; the idea of what you are doing is to *destroy* one `self` and provide another in its place.

That said, it's a little unclear what the `inout` variable is for. Why don't you just assign the new object in place of the old object?

```
func giveMeA( _ type: AbstractClass.ConcreteType) -> AbstractClass {
    switch type {
    case .concreteClass1: return AbstractClass.ConcreteClass1()
    case .concreteClass2: return AbstractClass.ConcreteClass2()
    }
}

var obj: AbstractClass = AbstractClass.ConcreteClass1()
obj = giveMeA(.concreteClass2)
```

The effect is *identical* to what you're doing. If you think it's not, you're just kidding yourself about what the `inout` parameter is doing.

Comment: Thanks. The purpose is also to copy over the original object's parameters to the new object, while substiuting the type. Will update my code

Comment: "The purpose is also to copy over the original object's parameters to the new object" I don't see that that makes the slightest difference to what I said, though. You can pass the original in, or send the message to the original, but what comes out is _another object_, and you are _substituting_ it for the original

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to propose a completely different way of looking at what you're trying to do.

Don't have an abstract superclass. Don't have multiple subclasses. Have *one* class with multiple functional variants. The functional variants are expressed by a helper object — a struct — owned by the class instance.

So to change functionalities, you just set the helper to a different type of helper. Basically, you give your object a personality transplant.

I have an app that works that way. I have four view controllers that present slightly different info in slightly different ways. But in fact they are *one* view controller and an enum with four cases that dictates those differences. Thus, at any time the view controller can manifest itself as any of the four types.

Comment: This is actually what I have been doing-- I defined the different personalities using an enum. It actually makes a lot of sense, because these classes are more like siblings without a parent (orphans?). Thanks!

Comment: Well it isn't what you have been doing in the example you showed and the question you asked.